# Split a string in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a string contains text "**AA55BB10CC1DD10E123**". I have to split the string and place it in List as text / value field like

AA | 55

BB | 10

CC | 1

DD | 10

E | 123

Thanks

Comment: What's your split criteria?  Any number of letters followed by any number of numeric digits?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are not a code writing service. While we're happy to assist with your *specific* question, please show us what you've written so far and what particular problem you've encountered. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: @DStanley, seems like from first letter to last digit before letter, if you understand me

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = "AA55BB10CC1DD10E123";
var letters = Regex.Split(text,@"\d").Where( t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t));
var digits = Regex.Split(text, @"[A-Z]").Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t));
var myList = letters.Zip(digits, (l, d) => new {l,d});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using my magic crystal ball, I have determined this was the answer you were looking for!

```
string[] split = Regex.Matches("AA55BB10CC1DD10E123", @"[A-Z]+\d+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => Regex.Match(x.Value, @"[A-Z]+").Value + "|" + Regex.Match(x.Value, @"\d+").Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try showing what you have tried, this is what you are looking for i think.

```
List<string> split = Regex("[A-Z]{1}[a-z0-9]*");
    split= reg.Matches(InputText).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: There's no reason to instantiate the list in your first line of code if you're going to just throw it away on line 3.

Comment: That is very true, it was more just to show the split using Regex.